# How to pass the value of observable to const/let variable in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
 <nz-select
            class="header-selection"
            [ngModel]="currentRoom$ | async"
            (ngModelChange)="switchRoom($event)"
            name="sbu"
            [nzPlaceHolder]="'Select Room'"
            [nzDisabled]="(roomList$ | async).length === 1"
            >
            <nz-option
              *ngFor="let item of roomList$ | async"
              [nzLabel]="item.description"
              [nzValue]="item.code"
              [nzDisabled]="item.code === selectedRoom"
              >
            </nz-option>
          </nz-select>
```

***TS***

```
selectedRoom: any;
constructor() { this.switchRoom();
    ngOnInit() {

    this.currentRoom$.subscribe(room => { this.selectedRoom= room;  });
    }
    switchRoom(event) {
        this.currentRoom$.subscribe(room => { console.log(room)  });
        }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to pass the value of `currentRoom` observable.
The problem is when I try to pass the value to variable it return `null`.

here's my code:

```
let data: any;
this.currentRoom$.subscribe(room => { data = room });
console.log(data);
```

but it doesn't display the value of currentRoom.
If I try like this:

```
this.currentRoom$.subscribe(room => { data = room; console.log(data); });
```

then every time I click the function `switchRoom()` it loop like this.

1 'Room1' then when I switch to another room it will be like this

2 'Room3' then when I switch again going back to room 1 it will be like this

3 'Room1' it loops

Comment: You are assigning it to the variable - however that assignment happens asynchronously while the console.log printing it is synchronous. You will log the value prior the assignment taking place. Considering researching concepts regarding asynchronous JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

`currentRoom$.subscribe()` is asynchronous, which means that `console.log(data)` is executed before the assignment in the `subscribe` function happens, thus `data` is still undefined.

Replace

```
let data: any;
this.currentRoom$.subscribe(room => { data = room });
console.log(data);
```

with

```
let data: any;
this.currentRoom$.subscribe(room => { data = room; console.log(data); });
```